# ConnectTimeout Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу написать бота для Телеграм, но, когда запускаю, выдаёт эту ошибку:

```py
2019-09-26 23:13:26,186 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectTime
out occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org',
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot926490118:AAF3_w_8q4jGufsI6ekUSLzO
7DxSune3nVU/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urlli
b3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api.
telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnec
tion object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect
timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', p
ort=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot926490118:AAF3_w_8q4jGufsI6ekUSLzO7
DxSune3nVU/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib
3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api.t
elegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\telebot\__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout
)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\telebot\__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, all
owed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packa
ge
s\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org',
 port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot926490118:AAF3_w_8q4jGufsI6ekUSLz
O7DxSune3nVU/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urll
ib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api
.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnec
tion object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect
timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', p
ort=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot926490118:AAF3_w_8q4jGufsI6ekUSLzO7
DxSune3nVU/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib
3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api.t
elegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-package
s\telebot\__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-pack
uests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org',
 port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot926490118:AAF3_w_8q4jGufsI6ekUSLz
O7DxSune3nVU/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urll
ib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02DE8DD0>, 'Connection to api
```

Comment: `Telegram` заблокирован на территории РФ. Вы используете `proxy`? И, пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос Ваш код.

Comment: Именно в Росси?

Comment: Нет. А я и не знал.  А это точно именно в Россие? (просто не когда не слышал)

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент `Telegram` заблокирован на территории Российской Федерации.

Процесс блокировки начался ещё 16 апреля 2018 года.
Подробнее Вы можете прочитать на Википедии: [Блокирование Telegram в России](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_Telegram_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8).

---

Для того чтобы обращаться к `API`, Вы должны использовать `proxy`.

***Пример:***

```py
from telebot import apihelper


apihelper.proxy = {
    'https': 'socks5h://255.255.255.255:65535',  # Замените на данные своего proxy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-то будет полезно мое решение. Когда я столкнулся с подобной ошибкой, то изначально ни прокси, ни ВПН мне не помогли.

Сначала я нашел файл **apihelper.py**, который расположен примерно вот тут:
*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\telebot*
там я изменил параметр CONNECT_TIMEOUT на 5. Думаю это полезно попробовать, но по факту это тоже не помогло.

Далее я немного изменил свой код. Было:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Стало:

```
bot.polling()
```

После этого бот заработал. Прокси из кода я убрал. ВПН при этом был включен через США.