# проблемы с установкой соединения с телеграм ботом

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

учился писать ботов в телеграм с помощью модуля telegram bot, было появлялось много ошибок, при том, что я писал  повторюшку, но всех их я решал.  Помогите с проблемой:Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))
и код:

```py
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите ошибку полностью (с `Traceback`). Могу предположить, что дело в блокировке Telegram на территории РФ. Не вижу, чтобы Вы использовали `proxy`. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1028417/339283).

Comment: По-моему вы засветили тут только что ваш токен. Да и @nomnoms12 прав судя по вашей ошибке. Думаю, стоит попробовать другой VPN

Comment: пожалуйста, объясните, как узнать данные своего  впн

Answer (score 1):

Установите Proton VPN. Он бесплатный, нормально работает. У меня установка VPN решила все проблемы